# Convert current time to utc time python with only using datetime package

Tags: python, time

What is the easiest way to convert current local time and date in format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` to UTC format in `time` package of `Python`? I'm using the following to obtain current time:

```
import time
time.strftime("%Y") + "-" + time.strftime("%m") + "-" + time.strftime("%d") + " " + time.strftime("%H") + ":" + time.strftime("%M") + ":" + time.strftime("%S")
```

Comment: Try this quick [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-zFPOx/0/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096) lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime.datetime` instead of `time`:

```
 from datetime import datetime
 time = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: note: "local time" is `datetime.now()`. `datetime.utcnow()` returns utc time already. `.strftime()` does not convert local time to utc. It converts datetime object to string.

Comment: Yes @J.F.Sebastian, that's correct. My answer was based on the `time` example in the original question.